# RegEx: How can I match all numbers greater than 954?

Tags: regex

I tried `^([0-9]\d|\d{4,})$` but it does not give the correct result.

Comment: You probably don't want to.  Regexes are for finding patterns in text, not evaluating numeric values.  Use a regular expression to find a number, and then compare it numerically in the language you're using.

Answer (score 29):

I **would not use a regex** for this since you will fall in an ugly chains of patterns.

However, if still have to or want to use one, you can use a regex like this:

```
[1-9]\d{3,}|9[6-9]\d|9[5-9]{2}
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/hG2iU7/7)**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

The idea behind this regex is:

```
[1-9]\d{3,}   --> This will match 4 or more digit numbers
9[6-9]\d      --> This will match numbers between 960 to 999
9[5-9]{2}     --> This will match numbers between 955 to 999
                  you could write this pattern as `95[5-9]` to cover 
                  numbers from 955 to 959 if you wish (it's up to you)
```

Comment: 9999 - 'partially' matched...I would not use a regex for this,too. :)

Comment: Thanks @nevermind, re arranged the patterns :P, it's working now

Answer (score 3):

Here it is:

```
([1-9]\d{3,}|9[6-9]\d|95[5-9])
```

See it [in action on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tL1gX8/3).

And a nice diagram :

[image: regex diagram]

Comment: Eheh i noticed something was going on :D I will put it back , thanks @dasblinkenlight

Comment: You have to re arrange the patterns since `99999` won't match :). Put `[1-9]\d{3,}` at the beginning.

Comment: Looks like mine broke the diagram generator... it displays 2+ times but should be 3+...

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following:

```
95[5-9]|9[6-9]\d|[1-9]\d{3,}
```

Explanation:

- `95[5-9]` matches from `955-959`
- `9[6-9]\d` matches from `960-999`
- `[1-9]\d{3,}` matches `> 1000`

Answer (score 3):

A bit long but designed to have only one possible path for each digit (to fail fast):

```
^(?:
[1-8][0-9]{3,}
|
9 (?:
      [0-4][0-9]{2,}   
    |
      [6-9][0-9]+     
    |
      5 (?:
            [5-9][0-9]*
          |
            [0-4][0-9]+
        )
  )
)$
```

Note that branches are sorted by probability.

Condensed:

```
^(?:[1-8][0-9]{3,}|9(?:[0-4][0-9]{2,}|[6-9][0-9]+|5(?:[5-9][0-9]*|[0-4][0-9]+)))$
```

Note: doing this with a regex pattern is most of the time inappropriate and complicated (regex are not designed to solve arithmetic problems). So if you can, cast your string to integer and test it with a simple comparison.

Answer (score 1):

`\b(?<!\.)0*(?:[1-9]\d{3,}|9(?:[6-9]\d|5[5-9]))(?:\.\d+)?\b`

This line will match leading zeroes and decimals, but only if the entire value is over 954. So it will match 955.62 and 0001253.125 but not 00954.999 or 125.967. [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hG2iU7/21)

To break it down:

`(?<!\.)` says not to match if there is a period immediately before the number. This is there to avoid matching things like 0.957.

e2:`0*` was added to make a full match with leading zeroes

`(?:[1-9]\d{3,}|9(?:[6-9]\d|5[5-9]))` sets up the match for everything substantial on the left of a decimal point. `[1-9]\d{3,}` matches any number equal to or higher than 1000. The other side of the | (or statement), `9(?:[6-9]\d|5[5-9])` matches any numbers in the 900s with another or nested inside. The internal or will match when the tens and ones digits are 60-99 or 55-59.

`(?:\.\d+)?` is a statement that matches decimals. The ? at the end makes it optional such that it will match numbers that don't have decimal points in them.

e2: The regex was wrapped in `\b`s to make sure it is it's own word. The regex will no longer match so1337, the769s, or 960things.

EDIT1: Forgot to make my . literal.

EDIT2: Made changes marked by "e2:"

Comment: I'm not finding a match against 955.62 or 0001253.125 using the RegEx string you presented.

Comment: 0001253.125 wasn't a full match. I'll update it to also match the leading zeroes. I haven't had any issues with it matching 955.62 though.

Also, it turns out that, according to the regex101 link I posted previously, the look-behind assertions I put in there don't work in js or golang.

Answer (score 1):

I was attempting to parse an application log file of database operation times captured for specific queries. The times are recorded in milliseconds (e.g. DatabaseTime=12035 ~ Database Time = ~12 seconds). To elaborate further, I needed to find cases where the application UI timed out after 120 seconds (i.e. DatabaseTime > 120000) so I could capture the timestamps on that same line.

Here is what I came up with for a RegEx pattern:

```
[1-9][2-9][0-9]\d{3,}|[1-9]\d{6,}
```

Many of you here are regex experts enough to break this down in your mind, but for those who aren't, I've tested this on regex101.com which also shows the breakdown of the Regular Expression for you: https://regex101.com/r/hG2iU7/28

Some thoughts/considerations on this subject (again completely relevant to the original question):

- I feel I took a very minimalistic approach to this, however, it
  appears to have satisfied the use-case, which required me to search
  through logs in NotePad ++ using the RegEx search option.
- I agree Regex isn't the solution to simulate such numeric operations
  (which would otherwise better be done using regex in combination with
  a programming/scripting language) but I have to tell you, if you
  need to quickly search through a log file in a text editor such as
  NotePad++, and you don't have the patience or client-privileges to
  create some pretty code or install a Python plug-in, regex may be
  your only quick (and admittedly GREEDY) option, and if thats the
  case, this is a completely useful scenario to know about in the
  workplace.

Lastly, please allow me to state: There'll be plenty of time for pretty coding and efficiency after you do your initial research....why take the time to code when you might not even find what you're looking for in the first place? A little research never hurt anyone...and everyone knows Rome was not built in a day.

Comment: It doesn't match decimals, but assuming its only Integer's the OP is after, I don't see any issue with your code. I'm editing the issue at the start out because this is a valid answer anyway.

Comment: @finnrayment Thank you I appreciate the feedback. Yes in my use-case the logs do not show any decimals, but you've stated a valid gap for others wishing to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I needed "integer regex" to programmatically simplify repetitive object relations. As many people have stated regex is used for detecting patterns in strings not comparing integers. However if you use integers to create an ordered relation between strings regex becomes the cleanest tool for determining that relation. **I do not** recommend using regex to compare a high volume of values but this will generate the necessary regex for most numbers (ran into issues with **10^15** and greater). Again thats just silly **dont use RegEx for that**.

**Note:** This only works for positive integers

greaterThan(954)

```
^([9-9]([5-9][5-9]|[6-9][0-9])|[1-9][0-9]{3,})$
```

lessThan(954)

```
^([0-9]([0-5][0-3]|[0-4][0-9])|[0-8][0-9]{2}|[0-9]{0,2})$
```

greaterThanEqual(1234567890)

```
^([1-9][2-9][3-9][4-9][5-9][6-9][7-9][8-9][9-9][0-9]|[2-9][0-9]{9}|[1-9][0-9]{10,})$
```

Javascript Code

```
const npiweblt = 'No Positive Integer (lt 10) Will Ever Be Less Than 0 (Duh)';
const npiwebgt = 'No Positive Integer (lt 10) Will Ever Be Greater Than 9 (Duh)';
const lessThanRegSingle = (int) => int >= 0 ? `[0-${int}]` : npiweblt;
const greaterThanRegSingle = (int) => int <= 9 ? `[${int}-9]` : npiwebgt;
const lessThanFormat = (prefix, leadInt, length) => {
  const lessButSameLength = leadInt !== 0 ? `|[0-${leadInt - 1}][0-9]{${length-1}}` : ''
  return `(${prefix}${lessButSameLength}|[0-9]{0,${length-1}})`;
}
const greaterThanFormat = (prefix, leadInt, length) => {
  const greaterButSameLength = leadInt !== 9 ? `|[${leadInt + 1}-9][0-9]{${length-1}}` : ''
  return `(${prefix}${greaterButSameLength}|[1-9][0-9]{${length},})`;
}

const integerCompareReg = (lessThan, equalTo) => (integer, asString) => {
  lessThan = lessThan === true;
  const ints = (integer + '').split('');
  const compareFunc = lessThan ? lessThanRegSingle : greaterThanRegSingle;
  const compareOffset = lessThan ? -1 : 1;
  let offset = equalTo === true ? 0 : compareOffset;
  let leadInt;
  let reg = '';
  let endOrVals = [];
  let secondToLast;
  let singleDigit = ints.length === 1;
  for (let index = 0; index < ints.length; index++) {
    const int = Number.parseInt(ints[index]);
    if (index === 0) leadInt = int;
    const str = index === ints.length - 1 ? compareFunc(int + offset) : compareFunc(int);
    if (index === ints.length - 2) secondToLast = int;
    const lastTwo = index > ints.length - 3;
    if (!singleDigit && lastTwo && ((!lessThan && secondToLast !== 9) || (lessThan && secondToLast !== 0))) {
      endOrVals.push(str);
      const orValue = index !== ints.length - 1 ? compareFunc(int + compareOffset) : '[0-9]';
      endOrVals.push(orValue);
    } else reg += str;
  }
  if (endOrVals.length !== 0) {
    reg = `${reg}(${endOrVals[0]}${endOrVals[2]}|${endOrVals[1]}${endOrVals[3]})`;
  }
  reg = (lessThan ? lessThanFormat : greaterThanFormat)(reg, leadInt, ints.length);
  return asString ? reg : new RegExp(`^${reg}$`);
}

const lessThan = integerCompareReg(true, false);
const greaterThan = integerCompareReg(false, false);
const lessThanEqual = integerCompareReg(true, true);
const greaterThanEqual = integerCompareReg(false, true);
```

Test Code (In case it I missed some edge case)

```
const test = (value, func, test) => {
  for (let index = 0; index < 2000; index++) {
    if (!test(index, `${index}`.match(func(value)))) {
      console.log('failed:', index);
      break;
    }
  }
}

test(954, lessThan, (index, result) => index < 954 ? result !== null : result === null);
test(954, lessThanEqual, (index, result) => index <= 954 ? result !== null : result === null);
test(954, greaterThan, (index, result) => index > 954 ? result !== null : result === null);
test(954, greaterThanEqual, (index, result) => index >= 954 ? result !== null : result === null);
```